# noindent first paragraph of subfiles

Tags: indentation, subfiles

I'm using the `subfiles` package and would like for the first paragraph of each included `subfile` to have no indent. However, I'd like to do this in the main file instead of adding `\noindent` to the beginning of each subfile. Is there a way to do this?

Here's a minimal working example. The file structure is:

```
main.tex
/sections
    one.tex
    two.tex
```

The contents of the files:

```
% main.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent\subfile{sections/one.tex}
\subfile{sections/two.tex}

\end{document}
```

---

```
% one.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

Paragraph 1.1. \lipsum[1]

Paragraph 1.2. \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

---

```
% two.tex
\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}

Paragraph 2.1. \lipsum[1]

Paragraph 2.2. \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

The output:
[image]

Comment: Can you add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? Do the subfiles follow some structur like chapters or sections? What does the start of your subfiles look like?

Answer (score 1):

Latex does not indent paragraphs following a sectioning command. You could exploit this behaviour and insert some empty and unnumbered sectioning command at the start of your subfile. This can also be done from within the main file.

One needs to compensate the additional vertical space an empty section commands inserts. In the following this is done by a quick hack, but with packages like `titlesec` this could also be solved in a cleaner way.

```
% !TeX root = main.tex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\subfile[1]{\begingroup\skip@preamble\vspace*{-2.66\baselineskip}\subsubsection*{}\input{#1}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\subfile{one.tex}
\subfile{one.tex}

\end{document}
```